# Adding Integers in Digit LCD Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to program an electronic skee ball table with Arduino, since the main electrical system failed a few years back from a power surge. I am replacing every electrical component, and I wanted the main microcontroller to consist of the Arduino Mega. I have figured out and programmed the ball detector and everything, I just need to know how to display the score on the LCDs. I was thinking buying a 3 screen simple digit LCD, and I need to it to display the integer after adding the score from the particular hole. So basically I need a code like "LCDPrint(CurrentIntegerOrScore+20" or plus another value.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to hold the value in memory and for consistency send the variable to the screen whenever you need to. It could be a global variable if you want or a score object that gets called.

Edit. Not specific enough code or OP:

Global variable style is the most straight forward way. Before setup() function put:

```
int score[2] = { 0,0 };
```

Since this array is outside the scope of all the functions it can be accessed from anywhere.

After this my preference is to create a function which would increase the score and do anything else required at the same time. The reason I do this is to future proof if I want to add a different display or add a noise later on, I could do it all from the one function.

Outside the setup() and loop() functions add a new function like this:

```
void addScore( int player, int amount){

    player -= 1;
    score[player] += amount;
    LCDPrint(score[player]);

}
```

Inside your loop() where appropriate call the function like this:

```
if (digitalRead(Trigger10Negative) == HIGH){
    addScore(1,20);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping here. There seems to be a problem in the code. Would you mind writing out a code snippet exactly how it should appear? I keep getting errors in the global variable style.

Comment: What does your code look like now? The code required is very straight forward. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Here is an example of the code.

if (digitalRead)Trigger10Negative == HIGH;
Global variable style int score[2];
To add to one player: score[0] += 20;
LCDPrint(score[0]);

Comment: Trigger10Negative is the const int for the output to trigger off the sensor. Once this is hit I want to add a value to the score that is currently on.

Comment: I have edited the code portions above to be more specific. Did you mean that Trigger10Negative is the const referring to the input pin?

Comment: Now I am getting LCDPrint is not declared in this scope..... And yes Trigger10Negative is input pin const

Comment: You are going to have to create that function. I don't know what you are outputting to or the protocol you are using. This is just an example of how you would implement the increasing score

Comment: I could help with that too if you need